# Would creating an Amazon ELB affect running instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have several Amazon instances running my company's websites in the default VPC. I want to create an Internet-facing load balancer and add new instances under it for the given VPC.

My question is would the creation of a new ELB affect request routing to my old instances unless I add them explicitly.

I am afraid that my websites would go off-line in the case I misconfigure ELB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ELB only affects instances registered to it and checked that it is healthy, otherwise it won't affect any other instances not registered to it and won't even be aware of them.

check this article:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-connection-draining-remove-instances-from-service-with-care/

it is mentioned: Elastic Load Balancer equitably routes traffic across all of the instances that are **currently registered** with it and deemed to be healthy based on configured health checks

also in this article: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-manage-subnets.html

it is mentioned: **After you attach** these subnets, the load balancer starts routing requests to the registered instances in the subnets.